# Confused about read/write bytes in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, encoding, ascii, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a binary file and xor each byte of it with a byte and then write each byte to a separate output file (also as a binary file) but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work in python.

EDIT: Now I'm having errors with the type at the .write() line. I'm getting string argument without an encoding. But the original file was a non text file and thus shouldn't be encoded in utf-8 or ascii right? What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#I originally had the utf-8 encoding line here but it didn't seem to be helping so I removed it
import sys

def xor(in,key):
    if (in == key or key == chr(0x00)):
        return in
    else:
        return chr(ord(in) ^ ord(key))

def main():
    inFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
    b = bytearray(inFile.read())
    #output = []
    outFile = open('decryptedFile.bmp', 'wb+')
    for i in range(len(b)):
        temp = xor(chr(b[i]),chr(0xf1))
        outFile.write(bytearray(temp))
        #output.append(temp)
    #print(output)
    #outFile.write(output)
    outFile.close()
    inFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: It's commented out here, but when output is printed it prints something like ['D','K','Ò'] etc. so that seems to be working?

Comment: `0xd2` and `0xb3` are not valid ASCII characters. ASCII only goes from `0x00` to `0x7f` and cannot encode anything outside that range. The correct way to do this is to read and work on bytes. Maybe you should ask for help with that rather than asking about converting to and from text.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I'll do that